# Difference between .app applications and files in /usr/bin?

Tags: macos, mac

I don't really understand the difference.  I tried putting a .app file in /usr/bin and executing if from the terminal but that doesn't do anything.  What kind of files go in there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wikipedia has a good article on [Application Bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Bundle)s.

In short, a `.app` is not a file: it's a directory tree with a specific structure. The actual binary that runs (ie, the equivalent of the binary you'd find in `/usr/bin`) is `PackageName.app/Contents/MacOS/PackageName`. However, you (generally) can't just copy that file to '/usr/bin' and run it, because it will expect to have lots of other files it needs inside the .app folder as well - for instance, many applications have the translation files that allow them to present the UI in different languages under `PackageName.app/Contents/Resources/de.lproj` (where `de` happens to mean `german`).

In some cases, the `.app` bundle may contain executables you can execute directly - for instance, I often use the `ebook-convert` binary from the `calibre.app` bundle, by running `/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/Resources/loaders/ebook-convert`. In this case, ebook-convert happens to be a self-contained python script and is perfectly happy being called this way - not all executables will be as happy.

You can usually start a `.app` by calling the main binary directly - eg, `/Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari` will launch Safari. However, this is a lot of typing - `open /Applications/Safari.app` is a shortcut that does the same thing.

`man open` has many more examples of using `open` to act as though the user had double-clicked on an icon in finder.

Comment: Just a note to add here. In the Finder you can see what's inside an Application Bundle (or any bundle) by right clicking on its icon and selecting "Show Package Contents" from the context menu.

Answer (score 5):

As Tomas Markauskas said, the .app is a bundle.

Why did you try to move a .app file to /usr/bin? I'm going to guess that what you really want to know is "how do I open a file using Foo.app when I'm at the command line?"

If I'm right, the answer isn't to move the .app file to /usr/bin. The right answer is to use the `open` command:

```
$ open -a Foo some_file
```

Using `open` without the `-a` will open the file with its default application -- just as if you double-clicked on `some_file` in the Finder.

Answer (score 2):

.app is actually not a file, but a folder (or Application bundle) with many different files in it. It also contains the executable files that you actually run.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run the app directly with the `open` command:

```
open /Applications/Safari.app/
```